# mongo in() clause sort by most matches

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Problem shows as follows:

my query:

```
db.goods.find({tags:{$in:["white","black","gray"]}}).pretty();
```

and data returned:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "tags": [
        "black",
        "blue"
    ]
}
{
    "id":2,
    "tags": [
        "white",
        "gray"
    ]
}
{
    "id":3,
    "tags": [
        "gray",
        "black",
        "white"
    ]
}
```

Now I want the query ordered by revelence of tags,that is,_id:3 is the most matches record of the tags field,_id:2 followed.

Can anybody help me with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation query to get the desired results.

```
db.goods.aggregate([
    {$match: {tags: {$in: ["white","gray","black"]}}}, 
    {$project: {"tags":1, "tagsCopy":"$tags"}},
    {$unwind: "$tagsCopy"}, 
    {$match: {tagsCopy: {$in: ["white","gray","black"]}}},
    {$group: {
        _id:"$_id", 
        counter:{$sum:1},
        tags:{"$first":"$tags"}
    }},
    {$sort:{counter:-1}},   
    {$project: {"tags":1}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

can solved by using aggregate

```
db.goods.aggregate([
    {$match: {tags: {$in: ["white","gray","black"]}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$tags"}, 
    {$match: {tags: {$in: ["white","gray","black"]}}},
    {$group: {
        _id:"$_id", 
        matches:{$sum:1},
        tags: {$push:"$tags"}
    }}, 
    {$sort:{matches:-1}}
]);
```